# What is the difference between aws system manager and aws cloudwatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am kind of confused with the difference between aws system manager and aws cloudwatch?

Could someone help me to get clear with the difference?

Thank you very much.

Comment: FYI, if you do a web search for an AWS service, you will find lots of "brief" explanations of AWS services. For example: [What is AWS: Understanding AWS and Its Services](https://www.simplilearn.com/tutorials/aws-tutorial/what-is-aws) and [What is AWS? Amazon Cloud Services Tutorial](https://www.guru99.com/what-is-aws.html#4) and [AWS 101: Overview of Amazon Web Services](https://www.sumologic.com/insight/aws/).

Comment: Thank you @Jonh, the ones that I found were the verbose ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have different purposes.

- [aws system manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/what-is-systems-manager.html) in the core of its functionality allows you to manage a **fleet of instances** as well as on-premise servers. Using the manger you can updated hundreds of instances with just a single command, execute custom scripts on all of them, monitor their patch compliance (i.e. do all your instances of interest have latest updates) and so on.
- [aws cloudwatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/) is primary used as a central location for **storing variety of logs**, from your applications (e.g. lambda execution logs), aws services and so on. It also allows you to monitor performance metrics of your instances (e.g. CPU utilization) as well as other resources. Other functionality is to **respond to live events** from resources (e.g. execute lambda whenever an instance is terminated)

Comment: Thank you very much @Macin, this helps me a lot, I am new to this platform, I voted up your answer, but I do not see the action reflected. Thanks

Comment: @EimisPacheco No problem. To accept, you have to press a "thick" under upvote/downvote buttons.

Comment: I have accepted your answer. You know that I asked the following question "aws snowball and aws direct connect are to migrate a high volume of data from on-premise data centers to AWS but what is the key difference?" when I have not asked this before and the platform has closed this. By chance, do you know the answer for this? as I am confused. Regards

Comment: @EimisPacheco Snowball is phisical device, as shown [here](https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse2.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.OPFW-zogDGDjJIWbZ7oHQAHaFj%26pid%3DApi&f=1) that you get from AWS to transfer large amounts of data (dozens of TBs), from your company to AWS. You request it form AWS, they send it to you, you copy your data to it, and send back to AWS. DirectConnect (DX) is physical, dedicated network connection to AWS. You use it to be connected to AWS without the need to use internet.

Comment: A huge thanks to you @Marcin. This clarifies my doubt. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

In short, AWS System Manger is a centralized tool to **automate management** of AWS resources.

Whereas AWS Cloudwatch is centralized tool for **monitoring** AWS resource **logs**.

These short video resources might help -

AWS System Manager -
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MK4ZoCs-muo&ab_channel=AmazonWebServices

AWS Cloudwatch -
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a4dhoTQCyRA&ab_channel=AmazonWebServices